# A piece fallen from my Dc power jack of Dell Inspiron 15 3000 (3501) laptop

Tags: laptop, port, dell-inspiron, adapter, charger

A piece fallen from DC power jack. I took picture of it below.

**frontside of the piece**
[image]

**backside of the piece**
[image]

I dont know whether it is fallen from charger adapter port or from laptop charger port.

**charger adapter port**
[image]

**laptop charger port**
[image]

Can i use charger without this piece? Why we have this piece? Im afraid to using charger without this piece (afraid of short circuit)? Is this piece is for insulation or simply for show?

Comment: Guarantee that's missing from the charger port.  I would avoid using it without.  You should take it in for repair.

Comment: It's function it to prevent a short-circuit between shell and center contact in socket. If one is comfortable with microelectronic repairs, it could be put back in the socket with the *tiniest* drop of cyanoacrylate cement on the flat surface labeled *backside*. Yes, it might ruin the socket if done incorrectly...

Comment: eBay sells what you need>>>>https://www.ebay.com/itm/403697923950?hash=item5dfe45776e:g:c30AAOSwztpimmU-&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA8G6gkR2fbYkHrbG1HJAlVKbixEKhB0kVt87ulDaGD%2BVA%2BefW%2FhSLQhUH%2Fo5Y1%2FQJhVrBOL06fOgEw8UPh99myXurVPunV11BvE9Scp1pE%2BTv%2F1MHUqJV9Fbhp%2BZXoV%2B12tpq1DU3es4hAmkFat6uDaocu9uAv500cJRUKTqPkQEgdo0EP2hCez0cNvh7c2coMCNIua0TeARmj0eUl0yWI0nBAJFNyP0WdPnYsQlh%2BKeVVtEgs0mRuVDBvMzyTe7xovk6wx0pxxCuwWUElyMc5HMQTQbOYEzN1ujXeGszx4bNcLGAVnT15whOh%2BS34XHF9w%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBMlvrch41h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s from inside the laptop’s port. It’s (sort-of) required because there are at least three contacts between the charger and the laptop: hot (+20V or something like that), ground and data (the charger tells the PC its power rating). On the barrel plug, these are on the outside of the barrel, on the inside and the third is the pin in the middle.

The piece exists to guide the barrel plug inside the laptop’s port and to prevent you from accidentally bending its contacts.

I recommend you get the laptop’s port repaired before charging it again. Because the power port is a low-tech part and Dell laptops are quite serviceable in my experience, this should be a relatively cheap repair.

If you *absolutely must* charge your laptop before you can get it repaired, you should insert the plug very carefully, centered and perfectly straight. Otherwise, you could bend any of the now-exposed contacts, making charging impossible and possibly causing a short-circuit.